# Narrowing down types of co-dependent, union-based, generic function arguments

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a simple function, that checks if `variable` is contained in an array `opts`

```
type IType1 = 'text1' | 'text2';
type IType2 = 'text3' | 'text4' | 'text5';

const foo: IType2 = 'text4';

function oneOf(variable, opts) {
    return opts.includes(variable);
}
```

What I want is to make the `opts` and `variable` co-dependent, so if I would call the function:

```
oneOf(foo, ['text3', 'text5']) //=> I would get OK
oneOf(foo, ['text3', 'text2']) //=> I would get a warning here, because `IType2` (type of `foo`) does not contain 'text2'
```

#### Approach 1

If I wrote:

```
function oneOf<T extends IType1 | IType2>(variable: T, opts: T[]): boolean{
    return opts.includes(variable);
}
```

I would get `OK` in both cases. TS would simply assume that in the second case `T extends "text3" | "text4" | "text2"`, which is not what I want.

#### Approach 2

If I wrote

```
function oneOf<T1 extends IType1 | IType2, T2 extends T1>(variable: T1, opts: T2[]): boolean{
    return opts.includes(variable);
}
```

I would get an error:

```
Argument of type 'T1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T2'.
  'T1' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T2', but 'T2' could be instantiated with a 
different subtype of constraint '"text1" | "text2" | "text3" | "text4" | "text5"'.
...
```

---

Can this be done at all in TS?

Comment: You can't write `IType1 | IType2` without the compiler just collapsing it into one big union.   Do [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/m05EOW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Would you be able to write the "Programmatic" solution as a part of the actual function definition (not just declaration), while preserving the `oneOf(variable, opts)` signature?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZbEKm)?  Not sure if I follow

Comment: Yes, something like this. Thank you.
I like the `ConditionalGeneric` and `RestUnionProgrammatically` solutions. Could you write them up and explain what is exactly happening in the `ValidArgs` type? I have a hard time wrapping my head around it, but I like how it simplifies the signature.

Comment: Okay I'll do it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T extends IType1 | IType2` is that `IType1` and `IType2` are themselves [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  The compiler will collapse that to just `T extends 'text1' | 'text2' | 'text3' | 'text4' | 'text5'` and so the compiler will not naturally group those in terms of `IType1` and `IType2`.  If you pass in a value of type `'text4'` then the compiler will infer that `T` is `'text4'` and not `IType2`.

So there are different ways to approach this.  One is that you can keep that union type in the constraint for the type of `variable`, but use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for the type of the element of `opts`:

```
function oneOf<T extends IType1 | IType2>(
    variable: T,
    opts: Array<T extends IType1 ? IType1 : IType2>
): boolean {
    return (opts as readonly (IType1 | IType2)[]).includes(variable);
}
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text5']) // okay
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text2']) // error
```

The conditional type `T extends IType1 ? IType1 : IType2` has the effect of *widening* from `T` to either `IType1` or `IType2`.  Note that the implementation of the function needs at least one [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) since the compiler can't really do much with an unresolved generic type... since it doesn't know what `T` is, it can't figure out what `T extends IType1 ? IType1 : IType2` is; such a type is essentially opaque to the compiler because the evaluation is deferred.  By saying `opts` is `readonly (IType1 | IType2)[]` we're just saying that whatever `opts` is, we will be able to read elements of type `IType1` or `IType2` from it.

---

Another way to approach this is to give up on generics and just think of different call signatures for `IType1` and `IType2`.  Traditionally you'd do this with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) like this:

```
function oneOf(variable: IType1, opts: IType1[]): boolean;
function oneOf(variable: IType2, opts: IType2[]): boolean;
function oneOf(variable: IType1 | IType2, opts: readonly (IType1 | IType2)[]) {
    return opts.includes(variable);
}
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text5']); // okay
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text2']); // error
```

And this is fine, but overloads can be a little iffy to work with and they don't scale very well (if you had `IType1 | IType2 | IType3 | ... | IType10` it might be annoying to write out the call signatures).

An alternative to overloads when the return type of each call signature is the same (like these are both `boolean`) is to have a single call signature which takes a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a union of [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
function oneOf(...[variable, opts]:
    [variable: IType1, opts: IType1[]] |
    [variable: IType2, opts: IType2[]]
): boolean {
    return (opts as readonly (IType1 | IType2)[]).includes(variable);
}
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text5']); // okay
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text2']); // error
```

That actually looks much like an overload from the caller's side.  From that you could make a programmatic version which calculates the union of tuples for us:

```
type ValidArgs<T extends any[]> = {
    [I in keyof T]: [variable: T[I], opts: T[I][]]
}[number];

function oneOf(...[variable, opts]: ValidArgs<[IType1, IType2]>): boolean {
    return (opts as readonly (IType1 | IType2)[]).includes(variable);
}
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text5']); // okay
oneOf('text4', ['text3', 'text2']); // error
```

This is the same as before; `ValidArgs<[IType1, IType2]>` evaluates to `[variable: IType1, opts: IType1[]] | [variable: IType2, opts: IType2[]]`.  It works by taking the input tuple type `[IType1, IType2]` and [mapping over it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to form a new type like `[[variable: IType1, opts: IType1[]], [variable: IType2, opts: IType2[]]]` which we then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the `number` index to get the union of elements of that tuple; namely `[variable: IType1, opts: IType1[]] | [variable: IType2, opts: IType2[]]`.

You can see how `ValidArgs` might be a little easier to scale up:

```
type Test = ValidArgs<[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>;
// type Test = [variable: 0, opts: 0[]] | [variable: 1, opts: 1[]] | [variable: 2, opts: 2[]] | 
//   [variable: 3, opts: 3[]] | [variable: 4, opts: 4[]] | [variable: 5, opts: 5[]]
```

---

Anyway, all of those versions should work reasonably well from the call side, depending on your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=1&pln=45&pc=30#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-draObJUFvWU-UG8mGRLGkumhrlJuWZqVeEtJ3Vmpeb03se3p13FrNVowd1t2t10UdfxdgPdjgi2sS1i0vhZxhmFG0JbtmYxNkmZLZJSDY0uUlQdnsBiRn6RoLGBJKpuQ5JFlhcF0ghjISEhgGQtGaFHBhuZTimzY4TBTSjhI46TpBtFJuQs53AB9Q9hy0HdPOi6iiMObroYMr7MaCpXpcN6HneEzHtYrwgGe0knIq17XOw1pUMej4Oi+-yukCUAAEoKMAACqEjRgAsjUJhSIkLEASh5Fbl03kFFR9HyEUKRducVEQf4-lhaixRFMQwW+aJ4FYRFeFFEUrbwQyTI8YYfF9gOuRDr4jGaGOE5hDRgQcVxJRCguIrLlR4nSupCwyas2mquq+m2ipp6yuebXmnJOkUIp3Vavaz6OiZ77QJZ8g2XZtgAAq6gA5tEsgyFIVjKC5bniPU9DQAAai5liaKWa3yBWCZDhIIDFCErDZQYBQwFAvRQM8EAgNYRjpIFIUJZhhQwEUyVg0U0WGlMBQSCYMjxNqRQkR5IHnt5XTxauyT+UDZ2JBdV03e9kFZM2RQhG2hFZcFuWctyhUjiVzFlRVWHVbVwkNSD4y0LDLXyppsnKvJ7DqkLF5acNqrWodhjHekVmsITxPRNdLgFAADFkUHYVAHBZHwWTCFTJG2krcAq+gOPirmusCWk2vRSmds5mkUHcp7rskO7iUG97UDUqlKaGrab2hYbyUcL7wO47mJtO1AfBx-7mHCMlwgwzMQA)

Comment: This helps. Thank you!